# Can you only style borders with tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I'm in the process of learning HTML and CSS, and I did a few simple websites with navs, sidebars, floating stuff, etc.

I got into a website that is made with table only (so I Googled, and saw that this was a bad thing, then I also Googled how to replace it but I can't find anything THAT IS NOT CSS3 - IMPORTANT, I DO NOT WANT TO USE CSS3 YET! ).

So basically, this site had 3 columns: the header above the table, and then split in 3 `<tr>` for the sidebars and the main content.

Each little sidebar on the right side is made of another table, and the borders have an image called like "content-right", "content-left" with a style to  "close the border and open it", and with the middle image that (I guess) it stretches to keep the style up.

I believe as I read around that tables are a bad way to style a website... but then I feel this is the only way to style a sidebar to make it look like I want from all the sides.

I hope you understand what I mean, I can't recall the website I looked and I can't find it anymore, I tried to explain as clearly as I could, I'm sorry if it was bad, I'm still in the process of learning as I said.

So basically, if you understood what I meant, can you tell me please, which others way (probably I guess with divs, or maybe borders? ) can achieve this thing?

Comment: have you tried using percent like width: 20% and so on ...

Comment: @PhilippBraun thanks, i think this gave me the input to get another concept to solve this problem without table : adding multiple "mini sidebars" in a sidebar. , i split 10% - 80% - 10% the table and inside the 10% i made the image with repeat-y. i guess this is the best solution without table. what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, understand that using `tables` isn't bad for everything; they're only considered bad when used to make the **layout**. Your website's **layout** is basically an outline that defines how your content is distributed and arranged.

In your case, here's a sample that only uses **CSS** and creates your same layout:

```
<div class = "header">
    Header!
</div>
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "sidebar">
        Sidebar 1!
    </div><div class = "main">
        Main content!
    </div><div class = "sidebar">
        Sidebar 2!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: white;
}
.header {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 140, 200);
}
.container {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px
}
.sidebar {
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(34, 177, 76);
    display: inline-block;
}
.main {
    background-color: rgb(0, 140, 200);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The first guy told me " try width:20% and so on ", and based on what you said, http://projectofsound.altervista.org/v1/ this site is bad in 2012, because its only made upon a table, so, to achieve the same thing with 3 columns, im guessing inside of a sidebar, i could have the 100% width divided into 10%|80%|10% so that the left and right would be an repeat-y image? would this be bad or a good practice to replace tables but also being able to have more control over the border of a sidebar? ( not all of it, just if you have multiple small sidebars on your right or left side, if you get wt imean

Comment: @MirkoBubba This depends on how you define *good* and *bad*. The only reason using `tables` for layout is considered bad is because they aren't meant to be used for layout. So it's semantically bad, but not ultimately -- using them probably wouldn't break the browser, but some people will make fun of your site's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You told that you learning HTML and CSS, if a learner its not good practice, try to create tables in 960 grid system CSS.
[This link Can Help You](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/03/fight-div-itis-and-class-itis-with-the-960-grid-system/)

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm not going to use a framework. i want all the work done by myself, doesnt matter if 960 grid can help me to make a site in 10 min rather than 5. but thank you anyway